# How to NOT use node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I type `npm install <PACKAGE NAME>`, it saves the files in a folder called node_modules, and this makes the project very heavy (200-400 files).

I wonder how the global packages works? I mean, the first thing that comes to mind is that when we install a package globally, is that the node.js will add the dependency on package.json and when the program runs, it goes to a folder on the computer where the packages are installed and goes use them.

The way i'm doing, each project will have the entire library inside, almost as if I had cloned that library repository into my project.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do? Avoid having node_modules folders committed to your git repo? (control this using .gitignore) Or avoid having duplicate node packages installed in multiple project folders? (perhaps use `pnpm`, though it's not a panacea).

Comment: @jarmod I want to install a package in my project, but I don't want install, example, express, in every single project I will create.

Comment: @jarmod I want install express in a folder, example, npm/packages, and the when the node needed the express, go to this path.

Comment: You *can* install things globally but you generally shouldn't as it will lead to versioning problems. Node package management is a complete disaster and, in my opinion, it is simplest to accept the penalty of having node_modules folders duplicated under multiple projects. You *could* try to optimize by using pnpm (in my experience it starts off well but eventually causes problems for other tooling) or yarn with workspaces (which is generally reliable, except perhaps for private package registries). Every now and then, review old projects and delete their node_modules folders to recover space.

Answer (score -1):

Normally if you're using a version control system like git, you're supposed to have a .gitignore file where the node_modules will be ignored.

Meanwhile, if you're bothered about your local computer storage;

If your operating system is a Linux Distro try installing your packages globally so that all the modules will be stored in a single node_modules folder in the home directory.
Do this using `npm install -g package_name`

If you're using windows this will [help](https://coderwall.com/p/453wgq/installing-npm-packages-on-windows)